# Retrieve statuses of given branch using github3.py

Tags: python, git, github, github3.py

I'm trying to retrieve the latest (last) description attribute of the status of a pull request by making the following call below. And, then create logic from there on how to process the pull request by the text in the description attribute.

How do I make the call to get the statuses of a given branch using the github3.py module (version 1.0.0a2) if I have the branch name (`for status in repo.commit(branch.head.ref).statuses()`)?

Please see this link, https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/#list-statuses-for-a-specific-ref and this one, https://api.github.com/repos/Microsoft/TypeScript/commits/moveModuleTransformToEnd/statuses  for further reference.

```
for pr in repo.pull_requests()
    for branch in repo.pull_request(pr.number)
        for status in repo.commit(branch.head.ref).statuses()
            if status.description == 'foo'
                do something
```

Comment: Does this not work? Can you explain how what you're seeing differs from what you expect?

Comment: I was receiving this error message: `TypeError: 'PullRequest' object is not iterable`.  I made this change: `for branch in [repo.pull_request(pr.number)]` and now everything is working fine.

Comment: Ah, I see. Why not just do: `branch = repo.pull_request(pr.number)` and then on the same indentation level, the for loop to iterate over the statuses.